How to decode non-JSON data using Alamofire library
I have using a API Response that is not in JSON format but wanted to still decode it, what are the ways that can achieve this stage.
Right now the response is failing, Failed to decode JSON: dataCorrupted(Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [], debugDescription: "The given data was not valid JSON.
I want to decode regardless of being a non-json response
I tried using replacing =(equals) with : and parsed the JSON and it worked, but after making few changes it stopped working
The Response is in this format
 Data = { "value" = "pair"; "value2" = "pair2"; }

My attempt
let validJSONString = rawString
                       .replacingOccurrences(of: "=", with: ":")
                       .replacingOccurrences(of: "NA", with: "null")
                       .replacingOccurrences(of: ";", with: ",")


Please add your attempt of solving this even if it stopped working.

let validJSONString = rawString
.replacingOccurrences(of: "=", with: ":")
.replacingOccurrences(of: "NA", with: "null")
.replacingOccurrences(of: ";", with: ",")

In your sample, and by reading the test, I guess that the raw value is { "value" = "pair"; "value2" = "pair2"; } (there isn't the "Data =").  let output = try PropertyListDecoder().decode([String: String].self, from: Data(rawStr.utf8)) works, but with NA as it seems to be a possible value, it shouldn't I think, so you'd still need to replace the "NA" with "" I guess, there might need some checks. The issue with replacing the ";" with "," is that in JSON the last one shouldn't be there before the closing }.

Be aware that this sort of "mash at it until it works" data manipulation is fragile. Unless you have a formal definition of the data format you are getting, you can't be sure that what works today will continue to work when the data changes and there is some new wrinkle in the data formatting you didn't allow for.

One option is to add another replace to get rid of the trailing comma
.replacing(/,\s*}/, with: "}")

So the whole conversion is
let validJSONString = rawString
    .replacingOccurrences(of: " =", with: ":")
    .replacingOccurrences(of: "NA", with: "null")
    .replacingOccurrences(of: ";", with: ",")
    .replacing(/,\s*}/, with: "}")


And in fact you can do this transform before attempting to decode by using a DataPreprocessor passed to responseDecodable.
